# Notations and definition clarification related question about Functors in category theory.

Tags: category-theory, notation, definition, functors

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1)}$ $\textbf{Motivation and Definition 1:}$

We have seen that a one-object category is a monoid, let us now see ia sense in which any category is a $\textit{generalized}$ monoid.  Given $\textbf{K},$ let

$$\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}=\coprod_{A,B\in {Obj}\textbf{K}}\textbf{K}(A,B)$$

be the collection of all $\textbf{K}-$morphisms.  Composition definees a $\textit{partial}$ function

$$\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\times\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\to\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}:(f,g)\mapsto g\circ f.$$

Let us see how we may recapture the identities of $\textbf{K}$ from this function:  We say that $u$ is an identity if $g\circ u=g$ whenever $g\circ u$ is defined, and if $u\circ f=f$ whenever $u\circ f$ is defined.  As before, each $f$ has exactly one identity $u$ such that $u\circ f$ is defined, call it $C(f)$ for the identity of the $\textit{codomain}$ of $f$; and exactly one $v$ such that $f\circ v$ is defined, call it $D(f)$ for the $\textit{domain}$ of $f.$  Thus our partial function $\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\times \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}} \to \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}$ satisfies the conditions:

$1.$  There are total functions $$C,D: \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\to \text{identities of } \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}$$

for which

$$D(D(f))=D(f)=C(D(f));$$
$$\quad D(C(f))=C(f)=C(C(f)); \quad \text{and}$$
$$f\circ D(f)=f=C(f)\circ f.$$

$2.$ $g\circ f$ is defined iff $C(f)=D(g).$  If $g\circ f$ is defined then $D(g\circ f)=D(f)$ and $C(g\circ f)=C(g).$  Moreover, if either $(h\circ g)\circ f$ or $h\circ (g\circ f)$ is defined, then both are defined and $(h\circ g)\circ f=h\circ (g\circ f).$
[In fact, given a partial function satisfying $1$ and $2$ we can reconstitute a category, with objects being the identities.]

$\textbf{(2)}$ $\textbf{Definition 2:}$

Generalized monoids cry out for generalized homomorphisms  $H:\textbf{M}_{\textbf{K}}\to \textbf{M}_{\textbf{L}}$ and the obvious demand is that

$$f \text{ an identity } \Longrightarrow Hf \text{ an identity}\quad (1)$$

$$g\cdot f \text{ definedy } \Longrightarrow H(g\cdot f)=Hg\cdot Hf.\quad (2)$$

For each object $A$ of $\textbf{K}$ denotes by $HA$ the object on which $H(\text{id}_A)$ is the identity, i.e.such that $H(\text{id}_A)=\text{id}_{HA}.$  Since $f\cdot\text{id}_A$ is defined for $f:A\to B,$ we have from $(2)$ that $$Hf=H(f\cdot \text{id}_A)=Hf\cdot H(\text{id}_A)=Hf\cdot\text{id}
_\color{purple}{AH}.$$

Hence $Hf,$ being composable with $\text{id}_\color{purple}{AH},$ must have domain $\color{purple}{AH}.$  Similarly, it must have codomain $\color{purple}{BH}$ since $\text{id}_B\cdot f$ is defined.  Thus $(2)$ says, in short, $H(A\xrightarrow{f}B)=HA\xrightarrow{Hf}HB.$

$\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{Definition 3:}$  A functor $H$ from a category $\textbf{K}$ to a  category $\textbf{L}$ is a function which maps $\text{Obj}\textbf{(K)}\to \text{Obj}\textbf{(L)}:A\mapsto HA,$ and which for each pair $A,B$ of objects $\textbf{K}$ naos $\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB):f\mapsto Hf,$ while satisfying the two conditions:

$$H(\text{id}_A)=\text{id}_{HA}\quad\text{ for every }A\in\text{Obj}\textbf{(K)}$$
$$H(g\cdot f)=Hg\cdot Hf \quad\text{ whenever }g\cdot f\text{ is defined in }\textbf{K}.$$

We say that $H$ is an $\textbf{isomorphism}$ if $A\mapsto HA$ and each $\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB)$ are bijections.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

1. (possible misprint?)  For where I colored coded $\color{purple}{AH},$ $\color{purple}{BH}$  Should it not be $HA$ and $HB$ instead?

2a.)  I understand in the definition of $H$ in $\textbf{(2)}$ $\textbf{Definition 2},$ that $H$ is a homomorphic map of generalized monoids.  But in $\textbf{(3)}$ $\textbf{Definition 3},$ $H$ only designated to stand for being a function?

2b) Also in the context of functors, what do $HA,$ and $HB,$ mean?  I know that in $\textbf{(1)}$  $H$ kind of serve similar roles as $D(f)$, and $C(f)$, but is never specific what it means in terms of mapping/functions for functors.

3. (about isomorphisms) I am unclear about the statement:  "We say that $H$ is an $\textbf{isomorphism}$ if $A\mapsto HA$ and each $\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB)$ are bijections."

In mathematical notations:  does it mean we have maps: $p:A\mapsto HA$ and $q:\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB),$ and both of them being bijective?

If so, $p$ being a bijection would mean that it is both surjective and injective.  But for the definition of surjection, what are elements in $HA$?  where $HA$ is never really explicitly defined, because it should start with something like:  For any elements $w\in {HA},$ there exists a....

For the case of $q:\textbf{K}(A,B)\to \textbf{L}(HA, HB)$, since $\textbf{K}(A,B)$ denotes the collection of morphisms, say $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}\in \textbf{K}(A,B)$ between objects $A$ to $B$ in the category $\textbf{K}$; and $\textbf{L}(HA, HB),$ denotes the collection of morphisms, say $\{Hf_i\}_{i\in I}\in \textbf{L}(HA, HB)$ between objects $HA$ to $HB$ in the category of $\textbf{L}.$  Then $q$ being injective would mean:  If $q(\textbf{L}_1(HA, HB))=q(\textbf{L}_2(HA, HB)),$ then $\textbf{K}_1(A,B)=\textbf{K}_2(A,B).$ But does $q(\textbf{L}_1(HA, HB))=q(\textbf{L}_2(HA, HB)),$ mean:  $\{Hf_i\}_{i\in I}$ is in both $\textbf{L}_1(HA, HB),$ and $\textbf{L}_2(HA, HB),$ similarly, $\textbf{K}_1(A,B)=\textbf{K}_2(A,B)$ would mean that $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ is in both $\textbf{K}_1(A,B)$ and $\textbf{K}_2(A,B)?$  Similarly for $q$ being surjective would mean:  For any $Hf\in \textbf{L}(HA, HB),$ there exists a $f\in \textbf{K}(A,B)?$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is a misprint yes. The $HA$ stands for $H(A)$, so $AH=A(H)$ doesn't mean anything in this context because $A$ is an object and not a homomorphism (amd vice versa for $H$).
2. If we take a category with just one object (and a set of arrows, but let's skip all the set theoretical details now), we get a monoid. If we add more such objects with their own endomorphisms and potential arrows between distinct objects, we get a generalised monoid. We may then think of the "structure" of a category as that of a generalised monoid, so our homomorphisms of categories should be homomorphisms of such. Now a functor can be seen as a homomorphism of generalised monoids = a function with extra conditions (just like your usual monoid homomorphism $f\colon M\to N$ is a function satisfying $f(m_1m_2) = f(m_1)f(m_2)$ and $f(1_M) = 1_N$). Notice how it is defined to be a function *satisfying two conditions*.
3. You should really be careful with the symbols here! You don't have arrows $A\to HA$, but there is $A\mapsto HA$. In other words, there is a function sending each object $A$ to an object $HA$, that is, a function from the set of objects of $\mathbf{K}$ to that of $\mathbf{L}$. Similarly, for any objects $A, B$ of $\mathbf{K}$, we have a function between the sets $\mathbf{K}(A, B)$ and $\mathbf{L}(HA, HB)$ sending an arrow between a pair of objects in the first category to an arrow between the corresponding objects in the second one. The bijections here mean the usual thing.

Comment: I fixed the notation for $A\mapsto HA.$  I am still a bit unclear about isomorphism being to mean the usual thing.  Specifically in the case of say injectivity, where a function say $q$ maps between the sets $\mathbf{K}(A, B)$ and $\mathbf{L}(HA, HB).$    Then being injective means  $q(\mathbf{L}_1(HA, HB))=q(\mathbf{L}_2(HA, HB)$ then $\mathbf{K}_1(A, B)=\mathbf{K}_2(A, B).$  Does this mean that both pairs $\mathbf{L}_1(HA, HB), \mathbf{L}_2(HA, HB)$ and $\mathbf{K}_1(A, B), \mathbf{K}_2(A, B),$  each of the pairs contains the same collection of morphisms?

Comment: Injectivity: If $f, g\in\mathbf{K}(A, B)$ ($f\neq g$), then $q\colon\mathbf{K}(A, B)\to\mathbf{L}(HA, HB)$ is such that $q(f)\neq q(g)$. Surjectivity: if $g\in\mathbf{L}(HA, HB)$, then $g=q(f)$ for some $f\in\mathbf{K}(A, B)$.

Comment: ah kk.  Thank you for confirming what I already suspect to be the meaning.  I really appreciate it.  :)

Comment: No problemo! :)